# There is error(compile-error-content-is-not-allowed-in-prolog) on the styles.xml files under the resp in my android project

Tags: android, xml

There is error(compile-error-content-is-not-allowed-in-prolog) on the styles.xml files under the resp in my android project.I have googled it but nothing worked.Here is the code which is in build,how can I solve this?

```
/* AUTO-GENERATED FILE.  DO NOT MODIFY.
     *
     * This class was automatically generated by the
     * gradle plugin from the resource data it found. It
     * should not be modified by hand.
     */
    package android.support.asynclayoutinflater;


    public final class R {
        private R() {}

        public static final class attr {
            private attr() {}

            public static final int alpha = 0x7
```

Comment: can you provide your styles.xml files?

Comment: Intially there was above code(which is posted in question) and was working fine.Now I change this to  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#00FF00</item>
        <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
    </style>
</resources>

Comment: @KhoaTran while I have changed this code, only white color is shown on layout in android studio inspite to show the whole layout  but  it work on device!

Comment: So you don't need to help to solve this one anymore, right? By the way, you shouldn't define layout_width and layout_height in your AppTheme style, and also fill_parent is deprecated (using match_parents).